# Buffer result differ with Shapely and QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, buffer, geopandas, shapely

I am creating buffers using both Geopandas/Shapely (0.8.1/1.7.1) and QGIS (3.10.10). I see slight differences in the results with both software. I have a projection EPSG: 25832 in both software. I am creating buffers around Germany cities (Berlin, Hamburg, Munich and Frankfurt) with specific radius (453, 327, 466, 161.5) in kms. See images below. With closer look the shift is visible. I want to find the polygon(s) beneath the buffers that intersect the exterior of each buffer. Therefore it is important to have the correct radius of the buffers.

**QGIS**

[image]

**Shapely**

[image]

What could be the reason for such difference ?

Comment: It looks like the buffers have different numbers of segments. The simpler shape of the QGIS buffer is making the long straight line, whereas the Shapely buffer has more of an arc shape (shorter, more numerous segments), and therefore reaches out from the center point a little further.

Comment: Makes sense. that means the result from shapely is more accurate. Isnt it?

Comment: You could also get different results if one is planimetric and the other isn't, or if they are using different coordinate systems or transformations.

Comment: Both are planimetric. Shapely can be considered more accurate with default settings but you can also control the resolution with the `resolution` keyword to get even more precise (or less precise) buffer. The same can be done in QGIS. Shapely defaults to 16 while QGIS to 5. Using the same number should yield same result.